# Django интернационализация - не работает переключение языка

Tags: i18n, интернационализация, django

Здраствуйте!
Делаю возможность на сайте переключаться между русской и украинской версией. 
Накатил *model_translation*, обернул строки в шаблонах которые надо перевести в тег {% trans %}, попереводил все с помощью *rosetta*. Также установил *locale_url*.

В settings.py прописал:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
MODELTRANSLATION_TRANSLATION_REGISTRY = "project.translation"
TRANSLATION_REGISTRY = "project.translation"
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', ugettext(u'Russian')),
    ('uk', ugettext(u'Ukrainian')),
)
```

Переключать язык через POST, так как это делается в django.conf.urls.i18n мне не захотелось, поэтому создал такое представление:

```
def set_language(request):
    next = request.REQUEST.get('next', None)
    if not next:
        next = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', None)
    if not next:
        next = '/'
    response = http.HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        lang_code = request.GET.get('language', None)
        if lang_code and check_for_language(lang_code):
            if hasattr(request, 'session'):
                request.session['django_language'] = lang_code
            else:
                response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, lang_code)
    return response
```

Делаю ссылку типа:

```
<a href="{% url set_lang %}?lang=uk&next={{request.path}}">Українською мовою</a>
```

Но переключение языка не происходит. 
При этом если вручную прописать ссылку http://localhost/uk/ то все работает, и шаблоны переведены, и записи из БД, однако переход по любой ссылке сбрасывает обратно на русский язык.

**В чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста!**

Вот мои middleware, может в них дело:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'localeurl.middleware.LocaleURLMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Чтобы языки переключались надо было добавить в views:
from django.utils import translation. 
Теперь языки переключается, но не меняется url, т.е. locale_url не работает. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

попробуй подключить localeurl в settings.py первым

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
#подключаем самым первым
'localeurl',
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы менялся URL, если не ошибаюсь, необходимо использовать  `i18n_patterns` следующим образом:

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here
    ...
)
```

И я, обычно, когда использую `i18n`, добавляю в `urlpatterns`     `url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),`

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here
)
```